# How to convert SQL select Count with group by clauses into LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I convert the following SQL query into LINQ?

```
SELECT [EmpUserName],[LeaveTypeName],Count([NoOfDays]) as 'Count'
FROM [NSL.LeaveSystem02].[dbo].[ProcessedCPLeaves]
GROUP BY [LeaveTypeName],[EmpUserName],[ProcessingDate]
```

Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is method syntax

```
 ProcessedCPLeaves
.GroupBy(item => new { 
                 LeaveTypeName = item.LeaveTypeName,
                 EmpUserName = item.EmpUserName,
                 ProcessingDate = item.ProcessingDate
}).Select (grouping => new {
                 EmpUserName =grouping.Key.EmpUserName,
                 LeaveTypeName = grouping.Key.LeaveTypeName,
                 TotalCount= grouping.Count()
});
```

Comment: is it " TotalCount => grouping.Count()" or " TotalCount = grouping.Count()" ? :-/
coz it gives an error when type as u have given

Comment: @CD1234, it is `=` and not `=>`.

Answer (score 2):

give this a try,

```
from a in ProcessedCPLeaves
group a by new 
    {
        LeaveTypeName = a.LeaveTypeName,
        EmpUserName = a.EmpUserName,
        ProcessingDate = a.ProcessingDate
    } into g
select new
    {
        EmpUserName = g.Key.EmpUserName
        LeaveTypeName = g.Key.LeaveTypeName
        TotalCount = g.Count()
    }
```

Comment: `group by new {a} by new` Never seen that syntax. Typo or me missing something? :)

Comment: oh yes! @JoachimIsaksson `:D`